# Delta method when function depends on n (and related question)

Tags: mathematical-statistics, normal-distribution, convergence, delta-method

I had a delta method question that I may be misunderstanding.

Suppose we have some estimator $\hat{Z}$ that is consistent and asymptotically normal such that $\sqrt{n}(\hat{Z} - Z)\stackrel{d}{\to} N(0, \sigma^2_Z)$. Now let's suppose we're interested in the distribution of $\hat{Z}\bar{X}$, where $X$ is some vector. Does the delta method still apply, since the value of $\bar{X}$ also depends on the sample size $n$? If we condition on $X$, then it should be straightforward (since we're simply multiplying by a constant), but here the value of $\bar{X}$ converges to $E(X)$ also.

I suppose the more general question would be, if $\sqrt{n}(\hat{Z} - Z)\stackrel{d}{\to} N(0, \sigma^2_Z)$ and $\sqrt{n}(\hat{X} - X) \stackrel{d}{\to} N(0, \sigma^2_X)$, what can we say about the distribution of $\sqrt{n}(\hat{Z}\hat{X} - ZX)$ (especially if $Z$ and $X$ are dependent in some way? What about joint asymptotic normality of $Z$ and $X$?)

Can this also be straightforwardly extended to the multivariate case where $Z$ is a vector (for instance, using Cramer-Wold theorem?)...is thinking about this with the delta method even the right way to go about things?

Sorry, I have tons of questions!

Comment: when you say $\hat Z$ is consistent, do you mean $Z$ to be constant and $\hat Z \to_p Z$?

Comment: Yes, $\hat{Z} \to_p Z$.

Comment: You might want to consult the multivariate delta method, in which you have a joint asymptotic normality of $(X_n, Z_n)$.Just given the marginal asymptotic normality of $X$ and $Z$, your conjecture is inconclusive.